# Detect when XMLHttpRequest has connected

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, xmlhttprequest-states

I'm trying to detect when a long-running XMLHttpRequest has actually connected to the server.

Right now, when I listen for the readystatechange event, it only fires when the request is finished. My test server sends the headers and some data, and after a long timeout (10s), it finishes the request. The XHR only fires events at the very end, and then it does one for each of the following states back-to-back: HEADERS_RECEIVED, LOADING, DONE.

Here is my browser code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(evt) {
    console.log('Request is now in state ' + xhr.readyState);

    if(xhr.readyState === xhr.HEADERS_RECEIVED) {
        console.log('Request has started');
    }
    if(xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
        console.log('Request is finished');
    }
};
xhr.send(null);
```

How can I detect when the headers have ACTUALLY been received? I'm assuming that I can't detect when the request starts, based on what's available in the API.

So far, I've come up with the following:

- Set request method to POST
- Send some data when the request is opened e.g. `xhr.send('something')`
- Listen for the `xhr.upload.onload` callback

Like this:

```
xhr.upload.onload = function(evt) {
    console.warn('Request has started');
};
```

This only works in Firefox and Safari though. Not Chrome or IE.

Comment: Do you know why it's taking so long? If there's no more data you're waiting for, would it be possible to move the ~10s operation onto a different page, so that you can exit and get the XHR going as soon as possible?

Comment: I'm deliberately delaying it. It's a test for an application that uses a lot of XHRs, and might need to detect when they've started or completed.

Answer (score 2):

The XMLHttpRequest object has 5 readystates

- 0 = uninitialized
- 1 = loading
- 2 = loaded
- 3 = interactive
- 4 = complete

You are just checking two of them in your code. Also you should be using an `else if` for efficiency.

Comment: or a switch for maximum efficiency

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the point of the question. I tried logging all the callbacks initially, and as I mentioned, a callback is called for readystates 2, 3 and 4 when the request finishes, not before.